# Integrate an exponential integral

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Integrate the following integral or prove that it is not integrable:

$ \int_0^\infty$ $\frac{e^{-2x}}{x} $$ dx $

I already know that the integral is not integrable, but how do we prove it? Should we write it in the series form and prove that the series is divergent?

Answer (score 3):

Compare $\int_0^1\frac{e^{-2x}}{x}dx$ with $\int_0^1\frac{e^{-2}}{x}dx$.

Comment: The function $ \frac{e^{-2x}}{x} $ is larger than the function $ \frac{e^{-2}}{x} $ only on the interval from 0 to 1. Here, we are considering an interval from 0 to $ \infty $. Does the comparison still work?

Comment: $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2x}}{x} dx = \int_0^1 \frac{e^{-2x}}{x} dx + \int_1^{\infty }\frac{e^{-2x}}{x} dx,$ and $\int_1^{\infty }\frac{e^{-2x}}{x} dx$ converges, so yes.

Comment: And divergence + convergence = divergence? Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: @HungDo Exactly.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you for the help. By the way, how do we prove that $ \int_1^\infty$ $\frac{e^{-2x}}{x} $$ dx $ is convergent? I know that from graphing, but how do we prove that by calculations?

Comment: @HungDo Compare to $\int_1^\infty e^{-2x}dx$.